# How to sort a DataView?

Tags: sorting, datatable, dataset, dataview

i am trying to sort a `DataSet` as desired:

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting1(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
   DataSet data = (DataSet)GridView1.DataSource;

   //sort data by e.SortExpressions

   //data.Sort   that doesn't work
   //data.Tables[0].Sort    that doesn't work
   DataView view = data.Tables[0].DefaultView;
   view.Sort = e.SortExpression;

   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Do not try and sort the `DataSet` - that's impossible. Instead, only try to realize the truth...

...you sort the `DataView` instead the `DataTable` inside the `DataSet`:

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting1(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
   DataSet dataSet = (DataSet)GridView1.DataSource;
   DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)dataSet.Tables[0];
   DataView dataView = dataTable.DefaultView;

   dataView.Sort = "TransactionNumber";

   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Except the grid doesn't come out sorted by the `TransactionNumber` column in the Data*.

Is there some `view.RunSort()` method that needs to be called before sorting *"takes effect"*?

### Bonus Reading

- [How to Sort Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670701/how-to-sort-dataset)
- [GridView sorting: SortDirection always Ascending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250037/gridview-sorting-sortdirection-always-ascending)
- [Introduction to Filtering and Sorting in DataSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b51xae2y%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [How can I sort a DataSet before doing a DataBind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228875/how-can-i-sort-a-dataset-before-doing-a-databind)